# Firebase setValue with Map with different types

Tags: java, android, dictionary, firebase

To update an object in Firebase, I'm using this code, that transforms my model into a dictionary.

This is the method that does such thing:

```
private static Map<String, Object> getPlayerData(Player player) {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(PLAYER_ID_KEY, player.getId());
    data.put(PLAYER_NAME_KEY, player.getFullName());
    data.put(PLAYER_SCORE_KEY, player.getScore());
    data.put(PLAYER_STATUS_KEY, player.getStatus());
    return data;
}
```

and this is how I use the result, setting it as a value for `theFirebaseRef` :

```
Map<String, Object> playerData = getPlayerData(userAsPlayer, newPlayerStatus);

theFirebaseRef.setValue(playerData, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {/**irrelevant code**/});
```

It works, but the `PLAYER_SCORE_KEY` ends up as a `string` in Firebase, when it should be an `int`:

[image]

I guess it makes sense because I'm doing a `Map` and declaring its values are of type `Object`.

Is there a way to make `PLAYER_SCORE_KEY` be an `int` when setting the value from a `Map<String, Object>`?

**Edit:**

The getter `getScore()` returns an `int`:

```
public int getScore() {
     return score;
}
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, score is stored as a String only when called from my app. When either the web/iOS client add/modify a player, they save it as an int.
The problem is that Android is the only one not doing so!

<sub>(Setting my model as a value as done in the Firebase documentation isn't an option because the Firebase property names are ugly and the server guy uses different names for everything...)</sub>

Comment: It's hard to be certain, but very likely that `player.getScore()` returns a string. If you make it return a number (e.g. `Integer`), Firebase will store that number.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen , player.getScore() actually returns an int!

Comment: But the database stores is as a string (you can tell by the quotes shown around the number). The string-to-int conversion does not happen automatically, you will either have to *store* it as a number too or deal with it in your code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think I'm following you. It clearly stores it as a String, only when called from my app, because I'm saving it wrong. getScore() returns an int. Just tried wrapping it with Integer.valueOf() (doesn't make sense but had to try), and it still saves it as a String. (BTW score is saved as an int when called from web/iOS client).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is your map parameters. You probably will need to make two maps, one with parameters (String, Object) like you have, and another of type (Integer, Object) to hold any integer information. Then set the values in Firebase accordingly.

Otherwise, you might could use Integer.parseInt() on PLAYER_SCORE_KEY to convert it to an integer, then set this value in Firebase directly instead of passing it in the map.

Comment: To do that I would need to make firebaseRef.setValue twice, right? Doesn't that make two requests?